# Converting unique string values to numbers in the attributes field using QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

[image: Attributes]

I'd like to convert unique labels C3nv to 1, C3pr to 2, C3rt to 3 and so on using the field calculator.

Is that possible or would I need to write a stand-alone script?

Comment: Do you have an exhaustive list of unique labels, or are you planning to use the expression on several layers with varying numbers of unique labels?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The very basic approach to this is:

```
CASE
WHEN "index" = 'C3nv' THEN 1
WHEN "index" = 'C3pr' THEN 2
WHEN "index" = 'C3rt' THEN 3
ELSE 0
END
```

Or a little more elegant and a huge time saver for a big list:

```
array_find(array_distinct(array_agg("index",order_by:=$id)),"index") + 1
```

You can also change the `order_by` part to whatever sorting you wish.